# Generalization in QGIS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop

I digitized tracks to the scale 1/4000 and I want to get out a map at 1/50000. I need a tool in ArcGIS or QGIS with its parameters that will help me to generalize the tracks to the scale 1/50000

Comment: This site use English as common language, you'll get more answer (and less downvote) by using it

Comment: All question should be in English on this site. You can use an auto translator and other people can help with spelling. https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error

Comment: Generalisation I have scanned tracks at the 1/4000 scale and I want to take out a card at 1/50000. I need a tool AARCGIS or QGIS with its parameters that can help me to generalize its tracks to scale 1/50000

Comment: i use Tools in the ARCGIS "THIN RAOD NETWORK",but I have to enter fields but I do not arrive. I need help to be able to generalize

Comment: Have you already checked the [Cartographic Line Generalization plugin](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/cartolinegen/)?

Comment: Yes,but After downloading it I do not know how to import it on Qgis

Comment: [» QGIS Training Manual » 10. Module: Plugins »10.1. Lesson: Installing and Managing Plugins](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/qgis_plugins/fetching_plugins.html)

Answer (score 4):

Try `vector - geometry tools - simplify geometries`. If google translated your question correctly.

Comment: What I should put in  "Tolerance "

Comment: Something that gives your desired output. Logically something in the magnitude of 12.5, since 1/4000 is 12.5 times more detailled than 1/50000. Depends on the number of nodes you digitized.

Comment: I just tried and the result was not satisfactory. I ended up with the same number of tracks on the way out. So my output card is still saturated by the large number of track

Comment: I have 15000 tracks

Comment: So you want a heat map. You could classify the tracks according to importance and/or traffic amount and only display the important ones.

Comment: It's a topographical map that you want to do. I tried a lot of windows but I do not get diminished my tracks

Comment: I was advised to use the tool  "Thin raod network " in ArcToolBox + Generalization  ". But two fields that I can not understand...